# Laravel - custom .env file

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel assumes that `.env` file should describe environment, and it should not be committed to your repo.

What if I want to keep both `.env` files for `dev` and `production` (say `.env-production` and `.env-dev`) in my repo and add some custom logic to which file should be used, for example based on current domain name.

Something like

```php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'prod.domain.com') {
    load('.env-production');
} else {
    load('.env-dev');
}
```

How can i achieve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Nadeem0035** gave me pretty good idea what to do

`bootstrap\app.php` right before `return $app;`

```
$envFile = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'prod.domain.com' ? '.env-production' : '.env-dev';
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use  Dotenv::load() for custom .env file

laravel 5.1 with vlucas/phpdotenv ~1.0

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'prod.domain.com') {
    Dotenv::load(__DIR__ . '/../','.production.env');
} else {
    Dotenv::load(__DIR__ . '/../','.dev.env');
}
```

OR

laravel 5.2 with vlucas/phpdotenv ~2.0

```
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__, 'myconfig'); // Laravel 5.2
$dotenv->load();
```

[PHP dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

In bootstrap/app.php

Comment: Thanks for answer, It did not work for me - since load is not a static method, also direct access to `Dotenv` may be not the best way, but you gave me good idea what to do and I come up with my answer - use `$app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);` instead. Thanks!

Comment: @SmxCde my first code was tested in laravel  5.1.* with vlucas/phpdotenv ~1.0 
[link](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/tree/1.1)

Comment: I'd like to add that you could point to a different directory with ```$app->useEnvironmentPath('/var/www/'.$_SERVER['VHOST_NAME']);```  It solved my shared codebase, different vhost problem.  Your VHOST config can then have a SetEnv  ```<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yoursub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yoursub/public

    SetEnv VHOST_NAME 'yoursub' ```

Answer (score 3):

I like to add a solution for people who have a **shared codebase for many vhosts** that all need different `.env` files for all the different  things, like **database connections, smtp settings etc**.

For every **vhost**, on Apache, create a vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your-vhost.yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/shared-codebase/public

    SetEnv VHOST_NAME 'your-vhost'

    <Directory "/var/www/shared-codebase/public">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
       AssignUserId your-vhost your-vhost
    </IfModule>

    ErrorLog /var/www/your-vhost/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/your-vhost/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

All vhosts have the same document root and directory, because it is a shared codebase. Inside the config we added a `SetEnv VHOST_NAME 'your-vhost'` which we will later use in Laravel's bootstrap.php to change the location of vhost specific `.env`.

Next create the custom `.env file` in a folder(fe. /var/www/your-vhost/.env) the alter `bootstrap.php` so that it loads the .env from the right location.

```
<?php

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Add the location of the custom env file
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/    
$app->useEnvironmentPath('/var/www/'.$_SERVER['VHOST_NAME']);

return $app;
```

That's all.

**[edit]**
I you want to target a specific database or want to generate a key for a specific .env, then you should put the VHOST_NAME in front of the artisan command.

```
VHOST_NAME=tenant2.domain.com php artisan key:generate
```

**[edit]**
When working locally and are using Laravel Valet, then you can add a custom `.valet-env.php` in the root of your codebase. 
https://laravel.com/docs/master/valet#site-specific-environment-variables

Comment: +1 for properly using `$app->useEnvironmentPath();` for informing laravel of the new position of the `.env` file. Others solutions are overloading `Dotenv\Dotenv` and will bring issues if you and running `artisan key:generate`.

Answer (score 1):

You've single .env file into laravel and you can define level of your app.

`APP_ENV=local`

OR 

`APP_ENV=production`

You can set configuration as per your requirement and not need to create new .env file to here. More about [Laravel Environment Variables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration) :
and Here's more descriptive help for you: [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not it: I still want to use .env files because it is convenient but I do not want all this bureaucracy and oversecurity that is unneeded when it is a small pet-project and I am the only maintainer. Schema proposed by default is good but too much effort for smaller projects.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar requirements during development, and wanted to do some ad-hoc 'multitenancy' on my dev box to test the same codebase against multiple databases/configurations. I didn't want spaghetti code with a bunch of if/then statements, so I came up with the following solution, which works great for my purposes (and doesn't require any mucking about with Apache, nginx or Caddy files):

Add the following in `bootstrap/app.php` right after the `$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(...);` lines:

```
// First, check to see if there is a file named '.env'
// within a subdirectory named '.env.{{HOST_NAME}}
//
if (is_file($app->environmentPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '.env.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '.env')) {

    // ...And if there is, use the directory as the new environment path
    $app->useEnvironmentPath($app->environmentPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '.env.'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}ER['HTTP_HOST']);
}

// Otherwise,  just use the standard .env file as the default...
```

Once this is included, the app will still use `.env` by default (meaning you can still use the standard `.env` file for any hosts that don't require customization), but *first* it checks to see if an alternative `.env` file exists within a subdirectory named after the hostname (ie, if the hostname is 'example.local.com', the file would reside within a subdirectory named `.env.example.local.com`).

You could change the code to remove the somewhat redundant `.env.` prefix from the directory name, but I like to add it to keep all the `.env.*` entries together in directory listings.

**One bonus of this approach: By using the usual name ('.env') *within* subdirectories, you should only need a single entry of `.env` to ensure *all* your custom configurations stay out of your git repo. No need to add a new `.gitignore` entry for each custom dot-env file.**

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share my two cents on this, for team working on different machines / hosts.
I create a directory `env` on app's root, containing:

- a `.master.env` file with the main and shared configuration.
- a `.name` file containing only a string with the environment's name for specific machine / purpose (e.g. "server1")
- the specific .env file matching the name defined above, e.g. `.server1.env`.

Then, in bootstrap/app.php:

```
/**
 * master config
 */
$app->useEnvironmentPath(__DIR__.'/../env');
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.master.env');

/**
 * config overloading
 */
$app->afterLoadingEnvironment(function() use($app) {
    $envFile = trim(file_get_contents($app->environmentPath().'/.name'));
    if ($envFile && file_exists($app->environmentPath().'/.' .$envFile .'.env')) {
        $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create($app->environmentPath(), '.'.$envFile.'.env');
        $dotenv->overload();
    }
});
```

Now you can selectively override configuration keys for specific machines and if you don't have security issues you can put the env files in VCS , as long as you ignore the `.name' file.

Working in Laravel 5.8.