# Laravel not reading env variables from different env files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

After upgrade from 5.0 to 5.8, laravel stopped reading env variables if the env is different than .env file.

For example, if i have `.env` file with the `USE_SSL=true` inside it.
`env('USE_SSL')` will be true

But if i have `.env` file pointing to another env:

`APP_ENV=dev`

and than i'll have `.env.dev` file containing `USE_SSL=true` , `env('USE_SSL')` will be null.

1. I tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:clear`, and `php artisan config:cache` - no luck. cached or not, i can't get the value.
2. I tried naming the files .dev.env and .env.dev - no luck.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Once the configuration has been cached, the `.env` file will not be loaded and all calls to the `env` function will return `null` : see in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#configuration-caching).

Comment: @jcHache i've added the value and than cached, but i added it in an edit to prevent confusion.

Comment: Another part of the same documentation specifies: If you execute the `config:cache` command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your configuration files. From where do you make a call to `env`?

Comment: I don't execute it in deployment

Comment: And where is your `env` call?

Comment: I don't think this sort of chained `.env` approach works, as it's not really how you're supposed to use `.env` anyways.

Comment: And you don't have your answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-5-2-not-reading-env-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer, but please note this **isn't** how .env file should be used according to laravel docs. It's just a way i needed to use due to some restrictions which required me to use different config files for each env, and load it in runtime. For correct usage of .env file check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration).

This is a way of loading different config files in runtime depends on where the APP_ENV is pointing. I'm marking this as answered since it's answering this specific question.

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=specific_domain
```

**.env.specific_domain**

```
USE_SSL=true
```

**Http/Kernel.php**

```
public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
{
    parent::__construct($app, $router);

    $app_env = explode("=", file($app->environmentFilePath(), FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)[0])[1];
    $app->loadEnvironmentFrom(".env.$app_env");

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alright if you really wanted to do this,

```
Route::get('renderEnvChaining',function(){
    $myCustomEnv = parse_ini_file(base_path(env('CUSTOM_ENV')));
   return $myCustomEnv['USE_SSL']; // This will return true
});
```

In my .env file i've mentioned this,

```
CUSTOM_ENV=.env.example
```

Now i in default env.example i put this

```
USE_SSL="true"  // This will return true
USE_SSL=true    // This will return 1
```

I just found that .ini and .env follows the same values, so i parsed .env file as .ini file,

Give this a try, i've never done this thing before, please concern with other developers before running this into production server

Comment: Several reasons. First, `.env` files are not `.ini` files. There are differences, like how you indicate a comment, so using `parse_ini_file` may cause issues. Second, your proposed approach doesn't populate environment variables. Third, it only functions on the single route in question.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you for making me understood this clearly, Okay so what if i use this https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv package to load env file, would that be a good approach ? and i know they both are different and they work differently. Here i found good solution to load custom env with package https://stackoverflow.com/a/38824174/5928015 , last thing should i update my answer with using packages or should i remove it for misleading ?

Comment: Ultimately, I think the question itself is flawed as it's based off a misunderstanding of how `.env` is supposed to be used. Each computer (local dev or server) has its own `.env`. Yours might be different from mine, even for the same app. The solution to dev-specific settings is to just put them in the main `.env` file on the dev server.

Comment: Yes that's what i get to learn from laravel doc. .env file is just for handle configuration, without .env we have to write values in each of the config folder files like database.php, etc, manually. So does anyone going to close this question ? because what framework gives as default we should always override and extends it's methods, right ?