# Multiple Docker Containers Using the Same Laravel Source

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I are using Docker for our deployments and for local development.  We are running the same Laravel application for many customers **.env** file.  In order to get our local to work properly with multiple sites we needed to figure out a way for each site to have it's own environment file.  We created a folder structure like the following.

```
docker/
 - src/ <-- Laravel App Here
 - local/
   - env/
     - site1.env
     - site2.env
```

The directory we are using for our environment files is being used in our docker-compose.yml file currently as a volume.

```
- ./local/env/site1.env:/var/www/html/.env:delegated
```

This is copying the proper env file to our containers `/var/www/html` directory and this works great.  However, where we are experiencing an issue is that when you do `docker-compose up -d` it is syncing the `.env` file back to our `src/` directory since we have a mount for that as well.

```
- ./src:/var/www/html/:delegated
```

Where the issues start to arise is when you open the `.env` file that is synced back to `src/`, not only is the file an empty file but if you add anything to it and save it will sync back to the container killing the site because it no longer has all of the env entries.

I would like to figure out a way to ignore the `.env` file so that it does not sync back to the `src/` directory.  Laravel requires it to exist in the `/var/www/html` directory in the container and I understand why it is syncing back down to the `src/` directory but I am unsure how to stop it or if it is even possible.

Am I doing this wrong?  I thought I would give configs a shot but I found that I cannot use configs because we are not running in swarm mode.

An example docker-compose entry is below

```
site1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DevDockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mysql
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_DATABASE: dbname
      DB_USERNAME: dbusername
      DB_PASSWORD: password-here
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/:delegated
      - ./local/client/site1/:/var/opt/client/:delegated
      - ./local/env/site1.env:/var/www/html/.env:delegated
    networks:
      - ournetwork
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - smtp
```

Comment: Not the solution you want but maybe a workaround, use a custom .env file based on some value (you can use host ip, env value setted on dockerfile, etc): https://stackoverflow.com/a/38835670/1580044

Comment: That's a decent solution, however with as many sites as we have and growing it would add a pretty complex switch statement or if/elseif logic to that file and probably not too easy to maintain going forward as we would have to remember to continuously add new sites to that file.

Comment: Can you build the application into the image, instead of mounting it as a volume?  That would avoid the specific problem you're having, and let you selectively update (and roll back!) individual containers to newer versions of the application.

Comment: If the `src/` dir is literally identical for every client then you should just build it into the docker image. Then you don't have to have this ridiculous problem where you're trying to mount something into a directory that is itself already a mount.

Comment: If we were to bake this into the image wouldn't we have to update the image with every build/release we make?  I am still new to Docker but I think if we were to bake it into the image we would have to retain an image for every version released and create new images several times a day with out releases to QA, Staging, Production.