Use different .env file for Laravel application?
Laravel comes by default with a .env file that comes under the root folder when you create a new project. I am having a fresh Laravel installation with this folder structure
root/
├── docker/
│   ├── php/
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── nginx/
│   |   ├── Dockerfile
│   |   └── default.conf
|   |__ webapp.env  
├── Laravel/
│   ├── app/
│   ├── bootstrap/
│   ├── config/
│   ├── database/
│   ├── public/
│   ├── resources/
│   ├── routes/
│   ├── storage/
│   ├── tests/
│   ├── vendor/
│   ├── artisan
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   └── README.md
|   |__ .env
└── docker-compose.yml

And this is how I am referencing both at the moment in the docker-compose.yml
...
env_file:
      - "docker/webapp.env"
      - "laravel/.env"

As you can see I have a webapp.env inside the docker folder, in which I am keeping any environment variables required for the Docker images I am using.
At the moment it is a bit hard to manage the environment variables as I need to jump from one file or another etc, so I was wondering whether it is possible to copy all the env variables from the .env file to my webapp.env and point Laravel to use this file instead of the default one?

This question is similar to: How to rename .env file in Laravel 8. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Not sure how your container is set up but if you are copying your files in it, then don't copy the .env files  at all, Docker will set the environment variables from your selected env_files in the container and Laravel will read them directly from the environment rather than from a .env file.

You can look this entry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823145/laravel-custom-env-file

I'm not sure this approach works,( without testing). We used this to map other files/folders into the project. It is the same theory you can use, too
services:
  app:
    env_file:
      - "docker/webapp.env"
    volumes:
      - ./Laravel:/var/www/html # this to map your app folder
      - ./docker/webapp.env:/var/www/html/.env # this to map your .env file


docker-compose down 
docker-compose up --build

This will map all the items in webapp.env to .env on the docker build.

You can move all the env variables with
cat Laravel/.env >> docker/webapp.env

and then create symlink
ln -s ../docker/webapp.env Laravel/.env

